# Next line in message sent is not working

Tags: php

```
    $e_body = "You have been contacted by $Name from the xxxxx contact forms. Their message is as follows:"."\r\n";
    $e_content = "\"$Message\""."\r\n";
    $e_reply = "You can contact $Name via email, $Email";
    $msg = wordwrap( $e_body . $e_content . $e_reply, 70 );

    php mailer code
    $mail->Subject = "$appName Contact Forms";
    $mail->Body    = $msg;
```

It seems the "\r\n" is just not working. Its not moving to the next line. What am i doing wrong. Any assistance???
Thanks!

I tried with html 
 in in place of the \r\n. Hence the code reads

```
$e_body = "You have been contacted by $Name from xxxx contact forms. Their message is as follows:"; echo "<br/><br/>";
$e_content = "\"$Message\""; echo "<br/><br/>";
$e_reply = "You can contact $Name via email, $Email";

$msg = wordwrap( $e_body . $e_content . $e_reply, 70 );
```

But this does not work either. Whats wrong here please. Any help?

Comment: Can you please try <br/> tag  may it helps you.

Comment: If it's Console, It should work else in browser, try with `<br/>`

Answer (score 1):

Actually the newline appears in the output, but browser don't render them.

If you want to see a line break at the webpage, use html `<br/>` tag.